# Pandas Timestamp index to list of date strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have the following index values in a pandas dataframe.

```
df.index[0:5]

DatetimeIndex(['2004-05-31', '2004-06-30', '2004-07-31', '2004-08-31',
           '2004-09-30'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='as_of_dt', freq=None)
```

How can I convert them into a list of like this:

```
['5/31/2004','6/30/2004','7/31/2004','8/31/2004']
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
In [11]: df.index.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
Out[11]:
array(['2004/05/31', '2004/06/30', '2004/07/31', '2004/08/31', '2004/09/30'],
      dtype='<U10')
```

Comment: list(df.index.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension and built-in string conversion may work:

```
[str(t) for t in df.index]
```